# window.location changes window.name, is this correct

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write an OSLC Delegated UI: 
(http://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/OslcCoreSpecification#Delegated_User_Interface_Dialogs)

Now it says that you should do the following:

1. read the return URL
2. send the response via the window.name variable
3. indicate that user has responded

So I've used this code:

```
var response = '{"oslc:results" : [{}]}';
var returnURL = window.name;
window.name = response;
window.location = returnURL;
```

But I'm seeing that when I set `window.location`, `window.name` is being re-set back to it's previous value before I set it with the line `window.name = response;` is this correct behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it is. What did you expect?

Comment: Setting window.location (re)loads the whole page. Not only is window.name `reset`, everything that you did on that page up to that point is.

Comment: I was hope whoever wrote the OSLC example knew what they were doing when it came to javascript and I was possibly missing something.

Comment: it would appear that the spec should have said set the `window.location` first, then the `window.name` 2nd

Comment: @sbarnby71 - that makes no sense either, because whatever you set after you set `window.location` is irrelevant, because the page (re)loads to the new location.

Comment: Hey Adam, I've tried it that way and it does seem to work, the page calls back to the parent and the 'window.name' is set to the value I want it to be